# A better conditional load test for Zepto

Tags: jquery, mobile, zepto

Using Zepto with a fallback to jQuery for unsupported browsers is a great way to shave a few Kbs off JS size for mobile devices. However, the current 'recommended' conditional load test:

```
<script>document.write('<script src=' + ('__proto__' in {} ? 'zepto' : 'jquery') + '.js <\/script>')</script>
```

is a pretty unreliable way to decide whether to load Zepto or jQuery. A number of the unsupported browsers (including older mobile browsers) will pass this test, but have problems running Zepto.

Is there a more reliable method (preferably using feature detection rather than device/browser sniffing) that would cover a greater proportion of browsers accurately? False negatives (i.e. where jQuery is loaded instead of Zepto, even though Zepto would actually work) are definitely better than false positives.

Answer (score 0):

That's a tricky question.  Whitelisting is only going to work if we know every special feature that Zepto uses.  You could add a sniffer for `Array.prototype.forEach`, `document.getElementsByClassName`, `window.JSON`, etc but you'll have to search through the code for anything you suspect will cause a defect or that you've seen cause a defect.  Some unsupported browsers, like Opera Mobile may pass, but these browser will probably actually work even though they are not on the officially supported list.

The most reliable way would be to *try* loading Zepto and afterwords check to see if `window.Zepto` exists and see if something like `$('#test')` works.  If not, load jQuery.  Of course, this would be madness.

Let me pose a question to you, though.  If a mobile browser doesn't support Zepto, you're probably looking at an older or less robust browser (with the exception of IE9 which is a special case).  Wouldn't it be reasonable to assume that trying to load a large complex library like jQuery would further degrade the user experience?  Load time would be awful.  If you are doing animations, the redraw rate would be unbearable.

The better approach would be to *when possible* base your design on the principle of progressive enhancement.  Build a website that works without JavaScript and then spiffy it up with Zepto if it is supported.  When it's not possible, consider that these browsers are becoming less and less common and may actually represent a small fraction of your users.  While we're stuck with these browsers for at least 2 years, that's a lot less time than we had IE6.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I would of course always build sites in a progressively enhanced fashion - but baseline cutoff for loading any JS is really a separate consideration to this. I'd absolutely ensure that less capable devices get a no-JS experience, but I'm really looking to identify the capable devices *above* that baseline (through feature detection, ideally) that I can safely use Zepto with, to squeeze a few more Kbs out for them. However I appreciate that this is probably  going to be unachievable without the whitelisting approach you suggest.